# typedef declaration contains #define directive alias

Tags: c++, types, alias, typedef, preprocessor-directive

I use two libraries in my project; let's say A and B for the sake of this question. Unfortunately, I ended up in the following situation:

In A.h:

```
#define ssize_t long
```

In B.h:

```
typedef long long ssize_t;
```

This leads to the following error, if A.h is included (i.e., processed) prior to B.h:

> E0084 invalid combination of type specifiers
> C2632 '__int64' followed by 'long' is illegal

My Question: What is the recommended way to deal with this situation?

I could make sure B.h is included prior to A.h instead. I could also `#undef ssize_t` before including B.h. Neither of which is perfect as it would become my responsibility to ensure the ordering of these includes or uglyfy my code respectively.

Update: It's not my code. The first (A.h) seems to be generated from [this](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/DCMTK/blob/master/CMake/osconfig.h.in), the other (B.h) stems from [here](https://github.com/rwinlib/hdf5/blob/master/include/H5public.h).

Comment: It's never a good idea to use macros to define type-aliases. And on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS the type `ssize_t` is a standard type that shouldn't be defined by third-part libraries at all. I'd argue that it's a flaw in *both* libraries, but A is most in the wrong.

Comment: Remove the code that says `#define ssize_t long`, if you wrote that code then you only have yourself to blame.

Comment: Although even without using macros, if A had `using ssize_t = long;` and B had `using ssize_t = long long;`, there would still be a conflict. Why do both of these files need to define what `ssize_t` is? Why do they disagree? If you consistently use `using` or `typedef` instead of `#define`, you could reduce the conflict by putting those aliases into namespaces, where actually it would be `namespace_A::ssize_t` that's an alias for `long` and `namespace_B::ssize_t` that's an alias for `long long`.

Comment: It's not my code. The first (A.h) seems to be generated from [this](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/DCMTK/blob/master/CMake/osconfig.h.in), the other (B.h) stems from [here](https://github.com/rwinlib/hdf5/blob/master/include/H5public.h).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: sometimes you don't have a choice. When you want to make a library portable and integrate third-party code (such as open-sourced), you may have to add definitions of the "would be" standard types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pinch, edit both headers, remove configuration logic around the problematic typedef/#define, and insert a simple typedef wrapped in #ifndef in both:

```
#ifndef my_size_t_defined
#define my_size_t_defined
typedef long long ssize_t;
#endif
```

If you are not afraid, you can try creating `sys/types.h` with these lines in your system includes directory instead (or adding them to your existing `sys/types.h`, but I gather your system doesn't have one). Configure the libraries again and see if they pick up the definition.

A less invasive solution would be to create a non-system directory with `sys/types.h` and configure both libraries such that they pick up that directory (most build systems have a way of adding custom compiler flags via environment variables).

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments around ssize_t in both header files. Those libraries are meant to be tuned for your system. In particular, one supplies a default in case sys/types.h does not define this type.

It is your duty to understand the system of macros that these authors have used, and make a coherent choice.

Unless A is precompiled, it should be harmless replace the #define long by the typedef long long.